# select document root using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, document-root

I can select the body and html parts of the document using

```
$('body')
```

and

```
$('html')
```

respectively, but how do I select the document root?

Comment: Why do you want to? You don't *have* to use jQuery for everything - it's perfectly fine to use javascript too.

Comment: Funny enough `$(document).html()` returns `null` here (using _jQuery 1.71_), while `$(document).text()` returns the expected result.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but to select the document you do

```
$(document);
```

To get the contents of the document I'm guessing you need the documentElement, which is just the same as the `<html>` tag in most enviroments.

```
$(document.documentElement);
```

Comment: `document.documentElement` points to the `html` element... just saying :)

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks adeneo :)

Comment: Surprising "document" is not inside of a string.

Answer (score 4):

The root of the DOM is always the `html` element.
You can get it either with `$('html')` or `$(':root')`.

The following assertions should always be true:

```
$('html')[0] === $(':root')[0]
$(':root')[0] === document.documentElement
```

Answer (score 2):

The Document interface inherits from Node, and represents the whole document, such as an HTML page. Although the Document node is conceptually the root of a document, it isn't physically the root - the root node is the first Element node in the Document, and is represented by its documentElement property.

You can select documentElement with following code:

```
var root = document.documentElement;
```

OR

```
$(document.documentElement);
```